# which java collection object is best when persisting entities using jpa

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am writing an application that parses n number of records each with m number of fields.  It is similar to parsing header information out of ip packets.  One difference is that the records I'm working with have arrays of fields for optional user comments.  My question is, what is the best java.util.collection object for persisting a collection of fields?  A set is probably best for what I'm trying to do, because of multiple 'comment' fields that must be unique, but are there any performance or serialization concerns when choosing one collection type over another?  Below is psedo-code for what I'm trying to do:

```
@Entity
public class MyRecord implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String filename;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=MyField.class, mappedBy="filename") 
    private Set<MyField> field;
}


public class MyField implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private String filename;
    private String filePath;
    private String fieldName;
    private String fieldType;
    private String fieldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take control by yourself for ultimate serialization performance, have a look at the `Externalizable` interface ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collection` to be prepared for future changes. Maybe someday `MyField` is allowed to be not unique.